# Android studio freeze when inserting or sync data from remote mysql database

Tags: android, sqlite

Sorry for disturbing guys.I have a problem here. I don't know why everytime when I tried to sync it will get me not responding anyway to optimize it?

```
    public void insert_icstk(HashMap<String, String> icstkValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String insert_icstk = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO icstk (Id,Code,Desc1,Shrdesc,Unit,Supitem,Uprice,ImportDate,ImportTime) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? ) ";

    database.execSQL(insert_icstk, new Object[]{icstkValues.get("Id"),icstkValues.get("Code"),icstkValues.get("Desc1"),icstkValues.get("Shrdesc"),icstkValues.get("Unit"),icstkValues.get("Supitem"),icstkValues.get("Uprice"),icstkValues.get("ImportDate"),icstkValues.get("ImportTime")});
}

public void insert_icstkuom(HashMap<String,String> icstkuomValues){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String insert_icstkuom = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO icstkuom VALUES ( '"
            + icstkuomValues.get("Id") + "' , '"
            + icstkuomValues.get("StkCode") + "' , '"
            + icstkuomValues.get("Uom") + "' , '"
            + icstkuomValues.get("Barcode") + "' , '"
            + icstkuomValues.get("Price") + "' , '"
            + icstkuomValues.get("ImportDate") + "' , '"
            + icstkuomValues.get("ImportTime")
            + "' ) ";
    database.execSQL(insert_icstkuom);
}
```

The reason I am using object on icstk is because I have an ('s) in the data. So no choice. Is it because of this reason making me lag?

Comment: How many rows ?

Comment: 4000 i think. Hmm but last time I didn't use object. It wont freeze.

Comment: Looks like [this FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19).

Comment: I will have a look thanks